# What is a fiber over a point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X\to S$ be a morphism of schemes.

First what does it mean to be a fiber over a point? Is it like the presage of $s\in S$ under the morphism?

Sometimes I see $X_s$ and sometimes I see $X_\bar{s}$. What are the differences?

Comment: In "geometric" situations, i.e. closed points of varieties over algebraically closed fields, it will indeed be the pre-image set-theoretically, but even in this limited setting there can be extra scheme-structure.

Answer (score 3):

Hartshorne defines the fibre of the morphism $f: X \to S$ over the point $s \in S$ to be the scheme
$$ X_s = X \times_S \text{Spec} k(s).$$

He observes that this is a scheme over $k(s)$, and provides an exercise (3.10) in which one can show that its underlying topological space is homeomorphic to the subset $f^{-1}(s) \subset X$.

If you are unsure of any of this, I recommend you review Chapter 2 Section 3 of Hartshorne, or the equivalent section of Vakil's notes/Gortz-Wedhorn.

I am unsure what you mean by $X_{\overline{s}}$.

Comment: +1. As for the notation with the bar, I imagine that OP is running into the notion of a "geometric point" of a scheme $S$ over a non-algebrically closed field $k$, which is defined as a $k$-morphism from $\text{Spec} \overline{k}$ to $S$ (where we've chosen some algebraic closure).

Comment: @hunter yes exactly. It was about geometric points. Say $X$ is a scheme. Can we always say it is there is a morphism $Spec(K)\to X$ for any $K$? If there is, how is it chosen?

Comment: A point $P$ of $X$ gives a map $\text{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{X, P}/\mathfrak{m}_P \to X$ where $\mathcal{O}_{X, P}$ is the local ring of $X$ at $P$ and $\mathfrak{m}_P$ is its maximal ideal. Write $K_P$ for the field $\mathcal{O}_{X, P}/\mathfrak{m}_P$. Then there is a morphism $\text{Spec} K \to X$ landing on $P$ if and only if there is a morphism $\text{Spec} K$ to $\text{Spec} K_P$, i.e. if and only if there is an embedding $K_P \hookrightarrow K$.